# regex extract match for every fourth comma in the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, parsing

I am trying to create a regex to get a output for below string, in sets of 4 comma separated values. I have tried something but it only selects each comma separated value. I don't know how to get the desired output.

The regex I tried:

```
".*?"(?=,|$)
```

**Data:**

```
"T","Success","2","2","T","Success","6458960","1","F,"You do not have sufficient credit.","6458962","1"
```

Desired out:

```
"T","Success","2","2"  
"T","Success","6458960","1"  
"F,"You do not have sufficient credit.","6458962","1"
```

**Update:** "The F is in double quote too, it was a typo, Sorry!"

"T","Success","2","2","T","Success","6458960","1","F","You do not have sufficient credit.","6458962","1"

Comment: Sure that you don't want to use a csv parser that supports quoting characters?

Comment: Also sure that it it's really `...,"1","F,...`? So the `F` is not enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @TimSchmelter F is enclosed in quotes too, the document has typo, I missed it to before posting, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following regex, but only if the F is also in enclosed quotes:

```
((?:".+",){3}(?:".+"))
```

This results in:

MATCH 1
1.  [0-21]  `"T","Success","2","2"`

MATCH 2
1.  [22-49] `"T","Success","6458960","1"`

MATCH 3
1.  [50-104]    `"F","You do not have sufficient credit.","6458962","1"`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE6xB5/1)

If the data is really in this inconsistent form, you have to parse it manually or modify the regex with an or condition.

Answer (score 1):

You just need `String.Split` and this:

```
string[] fields = str.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i += 4)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", fields.Skip(i).Take(4)));
```

Output:

```
"T","Success","2","2"
"T","Success","6458960","1"
"F,"You do not have sufficient credit.","6458962","1"
```

This presumes that this is not really csv data. Otherwise i would suggest to use a real [CSV parser that supports quoting characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes(v=vs.110).aspx). But it seems that they are broken anyway(`,"1","F,.`, so F is not enclosed in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:"[^"]*"|[^,"])*(?:,(?:"[^"]*"|[^,"])*){3}),?
```

1. `(?:"[^"]*"|[^,"])*` will match a values between commas, optionally quoted. Quotes are escaped as `""`.
2. `(X(?:,X){3}),?` where `X` is pattern #1, will match a sequence of four comma-separated values, and an optional trailing comma. The comma is necessary to correctly match blank values (`,,foo,`).

If the values are guaranteed to always have quotes, you can remove `|[^,"]` and `,?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex,but the regex has a problem:you need to trim then last `Comma`,and even there are much more `Comma` in string, not multiple of 4 `Comma`,it can also works fine

```
string patten = @"(?<=^(?:(?:[^,]*,){4})+)";
string text = @"""T"",""Success"",""2"",""2"",""T"",""Success"",""6458960"",""1"",""F,""You do not have sufficient credit."",""6458962"",""1""";
foreach (var tmp in Regex.Split(text, patten))
{
    Console.WriteLine(tmp.TrimEnd(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid regex unless you really need it, generally they can be harder to understand.

For fun here is a Linq solution:

```
var data = @"""T"",""Success"",""2"",""2"",""T"",""Success"",""6458960"",""1"",""F,""You do not have sufficient credit."",""6458962"",""1""";

var res = data.Split(',')
            .Select((x ,i) => new { Pos = i / 4, Val = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Pos)
            .Select(g => string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Val)));
```